# jquery post work with hebrew (unicode) but not with spaces, get not working with hebrew but does spaces

Tags: jquery, unicode, post, get, hebrew

i have tried load and hebrew didn't work for me so i changed my code to

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "process-tb.asp",
        data: data,
        success: function(msg)
```

(partial code)

not knowing that post and get is the problem for my hebrew querystring.
so know i can get my page to get the hebrew and english but no spaces are add to the text.

all pages are encoded to utf-8.

what is wrong with it?

Comment: Try to be more clear. I can't understand what you are asking

Comment: if you XMLHttpRquest with post, i have a field called content sent by the data. the field in every language is not getting the spaces. lets say the user type into the field "hello world" - in the page handling it to the db it will get trought the query "helloworld"
if i try get method it's ok, but unicode is not working anymore

Comment: wired thing... the page is encoded to utf-8 i have <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" codepage=65001%> <% response.charset="utf-8" response.codepage=65001 %> in the code but still - hebrew is not shown and special char lets say in french is shown like question marks what is wrong with that?

only in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed that with replacing spaces - so hebrew works with post and spaces are replaced

```
data = data.replace(/\s/g, "%20");
```